# playback of Matlab VideoPlayer file is too fast

Tags: matlab, video, video-capture

The playback of my Matlab VideoPlayer is too fast and shows people walking twice as fast.  I tried adjusting .FrameRate but no effect.  Am working with Windows 7 64-bit computer, and playing back using Windows Media Player.

Here is code:

```
%// Init:   
detection_video_file = VideoWriter( 'my_file');
    writerObj.FrameRate = 10;  %  but 100 60 30 don't have an effect
    open( detection_video_file );

%// The loop
writeVideo( detection_video_file, dispFrame );

%// And finally:  
close( detection_video_file );
```

Comment: How does it play in an external video player?

Comment: IS that your actual code? One reason it wouldn't work is that you're setting the frame rate of the `writerObj` object but you're creating a file with respect to the `detection_video_file` object. If that's all this is, this question should probably be closed as "caused by a problem that can no longer be reproduced or a simple typographical error."

Comment: You had mentioned VideoPlayer but your issue appears to be that VideoWriter does not honor the FrameRate property. Is that correct? Have you tried playing it back using an external player? Where are you observing this 2x speed-up?

Comment: Navan:  External player (Windows Media Player) is where I get the 2X problem.

Comment: horchler:  Thank you!  That was the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the correction:

detection_video_file.FrameRate = 5;